# conda confusing base environments

Tags: python, anaconda, environment, anaconda3

I am having a problem where conda displays different paths for my 'base' environment depending on what directory I'm in. Here is what I get when running conda env list:

In the root directory, I get:

```
base                     /Users/name/anaconda3
deepxube                 /Users/name/anaconda3/envs/deepxube
```

however, inside my project:

```
                         /Users/name/anaconda3
base                  *  /Users/name/anaconda3/envs/deepxube
```

does anyone have insights to how I can troubleshoot? I have confirmed that I can activate and deactivate the envs as necessary, it is just an issue of how they're being displayed.

Thanks!

expected results for conda env list to be identical regardless of pwd